# Anesthesia without amnesia?

Tags: memory, anesthesia, benzodiazepines, short-term-memory-loss

Usually, people "waking up" from anesthesia appear to be drunk/uninhibited and also have no memory of these events. I understand that this is usually because of drugs like Midazolam or Propofol which cause amnesia among other side effects.

Obviously memories will not form when a patient is unconscious but when they are recovering and awake, are there any drugs that do not have an amnesiac effect? I'm also curious if there are any drugs that don't cause lowered inhibitions.

Comment: I've been under propofol many times, and although I certainly remember nothing from the period when I'm unconscious, once I wake up I'm almost instantly alert and oriented, and I remember everything from that point forward. I've never noticed any lowered inhibitions.

Comment: @CareyGregory I certainly do have encountered disoriented patients after a surgery, but I'm unsure whether it was due to the anaesthetics applied during the surgery, or those afterwards (like morphin iv.), or due to the reason they had the surgery in the first place (especially with stroke patients). BTW: I have trouble recalling the events just prior to when I fell asleep and right after I woke up as well (without aneasthesia), and I'd consider myself healthy.

Comment: @Narusan Oh, no doubt. I was only commenting on propofol because out of all the anesthesia drugs, it seems to have the least residual effects and leaves the mind clear faster than any of the others. Other drugs are more likely to be the reason someone appears disoriented after surgery.